# Strange behaviour of an alphaApk's shortcut

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, apk

I have noticed that my application that is published to an Alpha test has a strange behaviour... The shortcut is launching the MainActivity again. Everything is working fine when it's installed via generated .apk

My Android-Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.YYY.XXX">
    <application
        android:name=".Infrastructure.XXXApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.BaseActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SettingsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SavedResultsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```